# *ngFor how to bind each item in array to ngModel using index

Tags: angular, ngfor

===final updated==

http://plnkr.co/edit/WKRBB7?p=preview

since I use ngModel in a form, I must add `name` attribue.

and my mistake is that I used same value as its name.

```
<form #myform="ngForm">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let staff of staffs">
         <td><input name="name" [(ngModel)]="staff.name">{{staff.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

after I change to belows, my problem is resolved.

```
<form #my2form="ngForm">
   <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let staff of staffs;let i = index">
         <td><input name="staff.{{i}}.name" [(ngModel)]="staff.name">{{staff.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

==========

sorry, I can't remember why I use names[$index].Name instead of x.Name.

maybe years ago I meet some mistake using x.Name, and then made a habit of using index.

---updated-----

I need a inline edit table, two-way binding.

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let x of names">
     <td><input [(ngModel)]="x.Name">{{x.Name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>

let names = [
{ Name:'jim'},
{ Name:'tom'}
];
```

initially the pages shows:

```
blank text field; jim

blank text field; tom
```

after I type 'aaaaaa' in the first text field, it becomes:

```
aaaaaa; aaaaaa

blank text field; tom
```

I think the page initially would show:

```
jim; jim
tom; tom
```

so, my problem exactly is, why the initial value is missing?

Comment: Please check the docs first https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Comment: Why don't you just bind to `x.Name`?

Comment: @TamasHegedus that might not work (not entirely sure) but I remember error messages that `[(ngModel)]="..."` doesn't work with template variables, but besides that, a good suggestion - definitely worth a try.

Comment: Are you using angular2-form?

Comment: Can you please provide plunker?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WKRBB7?p=preview

Answer (score 20):

It should be `[ngModel]="..."`

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let x of names;let i = index;">
     <td>{{ i+ 1 }}</td>
     <td><input [(ngModel)]="names[i].Name">{{x.Name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @micronyks I wasn't sure if he wants 2-way binding. Is `ng-model` two-way automatically? I don't know much about Angular1.

Comment: Yes it is by default in `Angular1.x` and you are welcome !

Comment: Thanks for this answer. and could you let me know how could we get values of [(ngModel)]="x.Name" at controller(component.ts file)?

Comment: Add `(ngModelChange)="methodOnController($event)"`

Answer (score 11):

in you case sir if you are using *ngFor for loop then i don't think so you need index. why don't you just use x.Name. here is the modified code.

```
<table>
       <tr *ngFor="let x of names;let i = index;">
         <td>{{ i+ 1 }}</td>
         <td><input [(ngModel)]="x.Name">{{x.Name}}</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

or can you try this

```
<table>
           <tr *ngFor="let x of names;let i = index;">
             <td>{{ i+ 1 }}</td>
             <td><input [value]="x.Name" [(ngModel)]="x.Name">{{x.Name}}</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. and could you let me know how could we get values of [(ngModel)]="x.Name" at controller(component.ts file)?