# How to use ngModel with the array input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I've multiple input fields that use `name="myInput[]"`. How I can use `[(ngModel)]` that can catch my `myInput`arrays?

```
<input name="myInput[]" [(ngModel)]="answer" value="abc" />
<input name="myInput[]" [(ngModel)]="answer" value="def" />
```

Does anyone experience these problems?

Thanks for sharing

Comment: not able to understand what you are trying to achieve here.. do you mean _bind_ an array such that each member is an ngModel to an input?

Comment: Yes exactly Suraj

Comment: ..then why are you giving name as array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652487/ngfor-how-to-bind-each-item-in-array-to-ngmodel-using-index

Comment: Ok..by the way..thanks..I need to try first.